# node.js and onoff - redirect on function return value

Tags: node.js, gpio

I installed node.js with socket.io and onoff on a raspberry pi.
On the webpage I want to implement a button that calls an onclick function that handles the IO's and returns 0 if success or <0 if it fails.
Based on the return value it should redirect to success.html or error.html
Unfortunately, after long searching of a possible solution I could not find anything.
I have an index.html and the webserver.js and have no idea.
Can anyone help?